# Symfony 2 form prototypes within prototypes - double $$name field

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony, symfony-2.0

I need some help with prototypes that are within prototypes. Symfony is very clever with generating form prototypes, but once you are one layer down (i.e. prototypes within prototypes), it reuses $$name$$ for both prototypes.

This is what a prototype field looks like for my entity. JQuery swaps out $$name$$ with the correct index value (based on number of child nodes)

```
 <input type="text" id="entry_entities_$$name$$_contactFax" name="entry[entities][$$name$$][contactFax]" value="" />
```

So far so good. But when you go one level deeper, Symfony uses $$name$$ for the next level down too - here is a prototype for the entity property:

```
<div id="entry_entities_123_properties" data-prototype="    
    &lt;label for=&quot;entry_entities_$$name$$_properties_$$name$$_name&quot;&gt;Name&lt;/label&gt;
    &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;entry_entities_$$name$$_properties_$$name$$_name&quot; name=&quot;entry[entities][$$name$$][properties][$$name$$][name]&quot; value=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
```

This means that (in this example with entity id 123) that all properties get ID 123:

```
name="entry[entities][123][properties][123][name]"
name="entry[entities][123][properties][123][name]"
name="entry[entities][123][properties][123][name]"
```

etc.

In my opinion the best way to solve the issue would be to use $$somethingelse$$ for the property - does anyone know where this is set - or does anyone have a complete example with JS on how to solve this? I embarked on a horrible find/replace of the second $$name$$ on each line, but it got very messy. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I couldn't find any guides on the internet.

Comment: You pass the '$$name$$' in prototype() function, can't you change it there?

Comment: Actually I looked into Symfony code after posting this. $$name$$ is hard coded into CollectionType. Take a look at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType.php

Comment: Right. [Not hardcoded in 2.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/CollectionType.php).

Comment: @meze thanks for that. I'm not sure if you've made my day better :-) Do I do some JS hacking or run my project on sf 2.1 beta?

Comment: Depends on how much time you have ;) 2.1 beta isn't announced yet. You can also define your own collection type with 'prototype_name' option (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This code is for symfony 2.0 (in 2.1+ you can just pass the name to `prototype()` function):**

You can create your own collection type with your required option:

```
<?php

namespace YourBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener\ResizeFormListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType as BaseCollectionType;

class CollectionType extends BaseCollectionType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        if ($options['allow_add'] && $options['prototype']) {
            $prototype = $builder->create($options['prototype_name'], $options['type'], $options['options']);
            $builder->setAttribute('prototype', $prototype->getForm());
        }

        $listener = new ResizeFormListener(
            $builder->getFormFactory(),
            $options['type'],
            $options['options'],
            $options['allow_add'],
            $options['allow_delete']
        );

        $builder
            ->addEventSubscriber($listener)
            ->setAttribute('allow_add', $options['allow_add'])
            ->setAttribute('allow_delete', $options['allow_delete'])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $defaultOptions = parent::getDefaultOptions($options);
        $defaultOptions['prototype_name'] =  '$$name$$';
        return $defaultOptions;
    }
}
```

Then just define a service with:

```
tags:
    - { name: form.type, alias: collection }
```

And use it as Symfony's collection but with prototype_name parameter.

Comment: I saw this answer after 3 days trying rewriting and differenciating the placeholders. I wish I saw it earlier. +10000000 !

Comment: @renoirb Good! But keep in mind it's a hack for 2.0. Since v2.1 you can just pass the name to `prototype()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Symfony, but using `String.replace()` in Javascript replaces only the first occurrence by default, so you could use that pretty safely.

```
$('mydiv').html
(
    $('mydiv').html().replace('$$name$$', 123).replace('$$name$$', 456);
);
```

If things are split onto different lines, and you want to replace in those lines, you could use `.split()` to break it into an array, `for()` over it, then `.join()` it back together.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I believe your idea would have worked, but the result would have been a lot of Javascript. Meze's answer fits into Symfony2 best practice.

Comment: Fair enough :) Mainly posted as an option, expecting someone to come up with a Symfony-relevant solution. Glad you've got a way you're happy with